# SystemD authentication makes me choose between the same user twice when using "systemctl start *service*"

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, users, useradd, bugs

I deleted and re-added my user, and now when I use systemctl start/stop service, it prompts me to choose to authenticate between two users, both being the same user.

How do I fix this?

This is what it prompts me after doing "systemctl start/stop **example.service**":

(I used mopidy as an example but it's the same with any other service)

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
Authentication is required to start 'mopidy.service'.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  thinkbox
 2.  thinkbox
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2):
```

Answer (score 2):

I know my situation is different from yours. I just hope it may help.

## TLDR

I had the same problem. I think the problem is caused by wheel is both my primary group and secondary (supplementary) group. I fixed it with `sudo usermod -rG wheel $USER` to remove wheel as my secondary (supplementary) group.

## Full Story

When I install Arch Linux, I use `useradd -m -g wheel xyz` which makes wheel as my primary group. This is not normal because most other guides I see online is to use xyz (my username) or users as primary group and add wheel as secondary (supplementary) group.

Commands below shows:

```
$ grep wheel /etc/group
wheel:x:998:
$ id
uid=1000(xyz) gid=998(wheel) groups=998(wheel)
$ grep xyz /etc/passwd
xyz:x:1000:998::/home/xyz:/bin/bash
```

One day I mistyped and accidently run `sudo usermod -aG wheel $USER`. This command add my user to wheel as a secondary (supplementary) group.

Commands below shows: (`id` and `grep xyz /etc/passwd` stays the same)

```
$ grep wheel /etc/group
wheel:x:998:xyz
```

However, everything seems fine so I didn't do anything. Until I met the same problem as yours. After reading online I found out `pkexec whoami` has the same behavior. I suspect systemd uses polkit which doesn't recognize that me user xyz's primary group and secondary (supplementary) group are both wheel and somehow mistake xyz as two different users.

Then I did `sudo usermod -rG wheel $USER` to remove wheel as my secondary (supplementary) group. Now everything is fixed.

Commands below shows: (`id` and `grep xyz /etc/passwd` stays the same)

```
$ grep wheel /etc/group
wheel:x:998:
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [the answer of xyz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/715039/360027), I understood that my user was added two times to the group wheel (ie `wheel:x:998:id2ndr,id2ndr` in */etc/group*. So removing the second one solve the issue for me.